# Automating initial MobilePush

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobilepush

Our goal is to be able to send MobilePush messages to Contacts based on data synced from Service Cloud.

Our app has the MobilePush SDK configured with setDelayRegistrationUntilContactKeyIsSet=true - and we are using the Salesforce ContactID as ContactKey. So, in Contact Builder, MobilePush Demographics are automatically associated with the correct record in the Contact_Salesforce synchronised DE. So far, so good.

Because Contact Key is not available in _PushAddress, my understanding is we need an automation that exports MobilePush Detail Extract Report, then imports it to a DE which makes ContactKey and DeviceId available to subsequent Automation steps. Ultimately we want to create a sendable DE that contains attributes from Service Cloud and MobilePush Demographics in a single record.

However, for MobilePush Contacts to be included in the MobilePush Detail Extract Report, we need to have sent them a message first.

So my question is: what's the best method to trigger this message?

One idea I had was to create an Automation that gets the necessary attributes from _PushAddress for records created in the past hour and trigger Journey entry that sends a "Welcome" Push.

Are there any other methods that don't involve a delay?

Answer (score 2):

With a little bit of help from your mobile developers, you can actually add a Contact Key to the _PushAddress table and have the value populated via the SDK.

**SFMC Setup**

As you may know, _PushAddress can be viewed and extended in Contact Builder > MobilePush Data. It's the `MobilePush Demographics` attribute set:

[image]

When you scroll to the bottom of the table, you can see the `Create Attribute` button. Click it and add a new Attribute where you will be storing your Contact Key, but be wary that the actual attribute can't be named `contactKey` as it is a [reserved word](https://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/MarketingCloudSDK-Android/sdk-implementation/device-contact-registration.html#reserved-words). SubscriberKey is not reserved btw...

That's all you need to do on your end.

---

**Mobile Development**

Your app is able to get the Contact Key and do a registration with that which is fantastic.

The developers need to just use the value one more time and utilize the Attribute feature ([Android](https://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/MarketingCloudSDK-Android/sdk-implementation/device-contact-registration.html#attributes), [iOS](https://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/MarketingCloudSDK-iOS/sdk-implementation/user-data.html#attributes) documentation) to save this value into the Contact Attribute you added in Contact Builder.

When done, this will populate the value of your new attribute in MobilePush Demographics (_PushAddress) and you will be able to query it with no issues.

Comment: Awesome, very helpful thank you Rafal! I didn't know we could create a new attribute on _PushAddress. Will try it, then mark answered.